# Problems averaging

Tags: javascript, media

I have the following function in javascript to calculate the average:

```
function calculaMediaFinal () {
    var soma = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i>5; i++) { 
        soma += parseInt(document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value, 10); 
    }

    var media = soma / 5;

    var inputCuboMedia = document.getElementById('ConcretizaObj');
    inputCuboMedia.value = parseInt(media, 10);
}

function ContarObjetivos() {
    let contador = 0;
    if(document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value) {
        contador++;
    }
}
```

But I have a problem, it's that I put in that at most there are 5 which is not true, because the user is who chooses how many results he wants. That is, the 5 can not be filled if the user only wants 4. How do I average without the number 5 but with the number of results that the user wants?

Comment: Your loop body will never be executed even once.

Comment: First things first fix your code. Then uou need to provide the user with some kind of input in which he will decide how many numbers there will be. Then you need to grab the input and use as a variable in your script.

Comment: @MateuszJ I have a table in php that gets the values entered per user, and what I wanted was the average of the filled rows. This works when I say how many rows I have, but if the user writes more or less rows than I said, it does not work anymore.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen This code works but has a limit, and the goal is to take that limit.

Comment: as said @RobbyCornelissen, your loop won't be executed. `for(var i = 1; i>5; i++)` initial value of `i` is 1. Alive condition of the loop is `i > 5`

Comment: @Cid What do you advise me to do?

Comment: What do you want to do with the "ContarObjetivos" function?

Comment: @TakitIsy It is another function that is counting the busy lines but is not yet complete, sorry to have confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop wasn't executed:

- In a `for`, the second parameter is the condition for which the iteration is going to be executed (true = execute). Changing `>` to `<=` made it work.
- I also merged your two functions so that a not filled `input` doesn't count.

Here is a working snippet where I used all your code:

```js
// Merged both function:
function calculaMediaFinal() {
  let soma = 0;
  let contador = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { // Changed > to <= here
    if (document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value) {
      soma += parseInt(document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value, 10);
      contador++;
    }
  }
  var media = soma / contador;
  var inputCuboMedia = document.getElementById('ConcretizaObj');
  inputCuboMedia.value = parseInt(media, 10);
}
```

```html
<input id="resultado1"><br>
<input id="resultado2"><br>
<input id="resultado3"><br>
<input id="resultado4"><br>
<input id="resultado5"><br>
<button onclick="calculaMediaFinal();">calcula</button>
<br> Media:
<input id="ConcretizaObj">
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

If you don't **need** to specify the "base" in the parseInt function, I also suggest you to use the unary `+` operator:

```js
// Merged both function:
function calculaMediaFinal() {
  let soma = 0;
  let contador = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { // Changed > to <= here
    if (document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value) {
      soma += +document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value;
      contador++;
    }
  }
  var media = soma / contador;
  document.getElementById('ConcretizaObj').value = media;
}
```

```html
<input id="resultado1"><br>
<input id="resultado2"><br>
<input id="resultado3"><br>
<input id="resultado4"><br>
<input id="resultado5"><br>
<button onclick="calculaMediaFinal();">calcula</button>
<br> Media:
<input id="ConcretizaObj">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your code works but it is forcing the user to fill in the 5 lines and the goal was to fill in whatever lines he wanted.

Comment: Glad it helped! @user9864805 I added a suggestion in a second snippet. It can be useful!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

- create `input` element and let user pass each number into it separated by space
- create `button` that will trigger the code that calculates the average
- create element that will store the result

To perform the actual computation

- get value of input field, split it at space `' '`, remove white spaces around each separate number using `trim`
- sum the array created in the previous step using `reduce`
- divide the sum by the amount of provided numbers

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const res = document.querySelector('p > span');

function getAverage() {
  const values = input.value.split(' ').map(v => v.trim());
  const sum = values.reduce((acc, v) => acc + Number(v), 0);
  res.textContent = (sum / values.length);
}

// 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
btn.addEventListener('click', getAverage);
```

```html
<input type='text' />
<button>get average</button>
<p>result: <span></span></p>
```

Where you pass numbers into input field one by one separated by space (try passing `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`) and then click button to perform the computation which then will be shown in `span` element.

Comment: I have a table in Php and I want the average of the rows that have been populated by the user, understand?

Comment: How can I use your code for the average of filled lines?

Comment: @user9864805 You mean that you have an html table?

Comment: @user9864805 If you need a code for some exact structure then you need to show how your html looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you want something like this. Create a new numeric input field that stores the amount that the user wants. Put the value of the input field in a variable and use it in your code? Also it probably needs to be '<=' in the for loop to be executed. For example

HTML add next line in your code:

```
<input type="number" id="userAmount" />
```

Javascript:

```
function calculaMediaFinal () {
    var soma = 0;
    var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("userAmount").value);
    for(var i = 1; i<=amount; i++) { 
        soma += parseInt(document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value, 10); 
    }
    var media = soma / amount;

    var inputCuboMedia = document.getElementById('ConcretizaObj');
    inputCuboMedia.value = parseInt(media, 10);
    }

    function ContarObjetivos(){
        let contador = 0;
            if(document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value) {
                contador++;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I did as you told me but give me NaN

Comment: @user9864805 Ahh yes sorry I made a mistake, I edited the variable amount in my answer, can you try again?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize where you changed.

Comment: In my answer I changed variable amount to : 'var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("userAmount").value);'